# Не могу обновить групповые политики безопасности

Tags: windows

Не могу обновить групповые политики безопасности на второй виртуальной машине которая входит в домен. Обновление заканчивается следующей ошибкой:

> С:\Windows\system32>gpupdate
>
> Updating Policy...
>
> User policy could not be upgraded successfully. The following errors were encountered:
>
> The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file `\\devops.epam.local\sysvol\devops.epam.local\Policies\\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini` from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and could be caused by one or more of the following:
>
> 1. Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
> 2. File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller)
> 3. The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.
>
> Computer policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:
>
> The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file `\\devops.epam.local\sysvol\devops.epam.local\Policies\\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini` from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and could be caused by one or more of the following:
>
> 1. Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
> 2. File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller)
> 3. The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.
>
> To diagnose the failure, review the event log or run `GPRESULT /H GPReport.html` from the command line to access information about Group Policy results.

Comment: Ну, вам же как раз пишут о возможных причинах. Вы их проверили?

Comment: вероятнее всего проблема с настройками виртуальной сети, если хост на Hiper-V и до этого все работало, за другие гипервизоры не знаю, не работал с ними. А так да, вам все в ошибке написали - нет связи с DC(проверяем сеть и DNS); задержка или сбой репликации - она не мгновенная, и внесенные изменения в глобальный каталог на одном DC могут быть не сразу доступны на других; недоступна (отключена, сломалась) DFS.